# Can not read property 0 of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, bitmex

> I get Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error. I just can't figure out the issue.

Although the program run's fine & I'm getting the desired output. But the error...

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w321.png)
[Console screeshot / resp object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDBKk.png)

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

var ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD");

ws.onopen = function(){
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"trade":"XBTUSD"}))
};

ws.onmessage = function (msg){
    var resp = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    console.log(resp);  

    var price = resp['data'][0].price; // can not read property 0 of undefined :/

    console.log('Price is : ' + price);


};

});
```

Comment: What is the structure of msg parameter in onmessage function? I ask it because maybe resp does not have data property, because you already stored msg.data in resp.

Comment: Can you tell us what the console log is printing

Comment: I've attached the screenshot of the console.

Comment: can you add the  console.log(resp);  result in the question ?

Comment: there is no `data` property in any of the `resp` variable log.

Comment: console.log(resp); 
https://imgur.com/a/oKiaPNw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `resp/resp.data` is null or not. If `resp/resp.data` is null, there are nothing at index `0`.

```
   ws.onmessage = function (msg){
       var resp = JSON.parse(msg.data);
       console.log('Data : ' + data);  
       console.log('resp: ' + resp);  
       var price;
       if(resp && resp.data){
          price = resp.data[0].price; // can not read property 0 of undefined :/
       }

       console.log('Price is : ' + price);

      //document.getElementById('btcPrice').value = price;

   };
```

Comment: I would recommand to use an utility function, made by the facebook team, in order to prevent theses situations : https://github.com/facebookincubator/idx

Comment: The error is gone but now price is undefined.
I'll post screenshot of console.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try this.If `0` is undefined, then there is no price to deduce.

Comment: now it says : Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Before `if(){}`, print `resp` ,  look the length of it and check are there `resp['data']` present

Comment: Btw the problem isn't the error, the problem is that it works even if there's an error. This is really weird and it deserves to be understood

Comment: Yap. You are right @CristianTraìna, thats why we need to see the `resp` value by printing this

Comment: @ImGrooot, please show us what is the value of `resp`

Comment: also it seems like the code is executing more than once. so the first time error and the second time correct result that is also a possibility

Comment: @ImGrooot, try this `price = resp.data[0].price;` UPD is my answer. And let us know if it works :)

Comment: @ImGrooot you cannot trust the console.log(resp) because it may replace with the new refernce data

Comment: @HarunurRashid vote cast by those less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score. :D
when my reputation is 15 or above 15... I'll come back to vote for you.
Thanks again.